What do I put for yaml entrypoint?
The doc says entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
My question is what do I put in place of main, I've tried the root file of my app which is savapp but it just returns ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'savapp'.
I've tried a few different files in my app directory but none of them work. I'm trying to run gcloud app deploy in the command line.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The final argument to gunicorn is <python module name>:<function name>, where <python module name> is the name of something that you can successfully import if you were to run python in the same directory from which you're starting gunicorn (and <function name> is the name of a function contained in that module).

The name of your python file where you have defined app
